# WildCards - producer <? extends V>

Tags: java, wildcards

Почему producer может принимать null (и только null)?

Принцип PECS мне понятен. Если метод читает данные из аргумента, то аргумент producer и надо .

```
private static void test1(List<? extends Dog> test) {
    test.add(null); // почему можно null?
}

static class Animal {
}
static class Pet extends Animal {
}
static class Dog extends Pet {
}
static class SpecialDog extends Dog {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

null это значение по умолчанию любых ссылочных типов. По тому и можно ...

Answer (score 0):

Представим, что у класса Dog есть подклассы Вulldog и Poodle. Сигнатура метода test1 позволяет передать в качестве аргумента, как List<Вulldog>, так и List, мы не можем добавить в такой List объект класса Dog,так как не знаем, как был типизирован List, потому только null. Если бы могли так сделать, то представим, что передан List<Вulldog>, мы добавили в него объект Poodle, в вызывающем коде из коллекции достали элемент и получили ClassCastException, тк ожидается Вulldog, а получили Poodle.